# How to determine whether an insert into database operation succeeded?

Tags: php, mysql

I insert some data from a php foreach. And when the data insert, I make sure if the data has already existed in 2 tables? if not, insert, else jump.

But in this process, how can I know each item data has been inserted or no?

```
{
//some foreach process get $title, $name, $date
mysql_query("INSERT INTO table1 (title,name,date) SELECT '".$title."','".$name."','".$date."' FROM dual WHERE not exists (SELECT title FROM table1 WHERE table1.title = '".$title."') AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT title FROM table2 WHERE table2.title = '".$title."')");
      //I want to  add some judge like this:
      //if this item insert {
       //do some stuff;
      //} else {
       //do some stuff;
      //}     
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From http://php.net/function.mysql-query:

> For other type of SQL statements, **INSERT**, UPDATE, DELETE, DROP, etc, mysql_query() returns **TRUE on success** or **FALSE on error**.

Comment: Is there some kind of error logging when these operations fail?

Answer (score 3):

**mysql_query** always returns a value.  It returns a TRUE when INSERT is successful.  See code below.  Hope this helps.  :)

```
 $result=mysql_query($sql);

 // SUCCESSFUL
 if($result){
      echo "Successful";
 }
 // NOT SUCCESSFUL
 else {
      echo "Not inserted";
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

This might help

```
If (mysql_query($sql)){
//Success
}else{
//Failure
echo mysql_error(); //Reason
}
```